# Rspec 3.8, request spec, unable to set route with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails, rspec3

In the request spec for the show method I want to test the route `cars/:id`.
If I write the path like the following I get a redirect to my root exception.

```
describe '#show' do
  let(:car) { create :car}

  it 'renders a partial' do
    get car_url(car.id)
    expect(response).to render_template(:template)
  end
end

# expecting <"template"> but was a redirect to <http://admin.example.com/>
```

When I change `get car_url,car.id` with `get cars` to test the #index method everything works fine. But I do not see myself able to add a id parameter to the route.

In the console the app object gives me:

```
irb(main):001:0> app.car_url(2)                                                                                                                                                     
=> "http://www.example.com/cars/2"
```

so the route is there. The factory is also a valid object saved to the database.

Comment: Does `car_url` require authentication?

Comment: Yes. It does require authentication. But i left it out for simplification, because the index method works